# How to set a delay between function calls

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a button with a ripple effect like Material UI. I've reached the goal I wanted, but I got one problem with the cleanup of the ripples that finished their animations.

Currently, the ripples are stored in a state which starts as an empty array. This is the structure of one ripple

```
{ 
  id: number,
  width: string, 
  height:string, 
  top: string, 
  left: string, 
  visible: boolean 
}
```

I have a `onMouseDown` listener at the button, and inside the button there's a span that renders the created ripples:

```
 <button 
  onMouseDown={handleRippleAddition}
  onMouseUp={handleRippleRemoval}
 >
   Text
   <span> //Ripples container
     {
       ripples.map(() => {
         //renders the ripples from the ripples state
       })
      }
   <span/>
 </button>
```

There's also a  `onMouseUp` that changes the `visible` property of the last added ripple which triggers a `fadeOut` animation.

My issue is at the function `handleRippleRemoval` called at `onMouseUp` event. I need a delay for each call, so when this function is called it needs to wait 550ms so the fadeOut animation finishes, and then I can remove the ripple that finished the full animation.

I've tried multiple approaches; the closest one to work was this one:

```
function timeout(delay: number) {
   return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, delay))
 }

 async function handleRippleRemoval() {
   await timeout(550)
   setRipples((prevState) => {
   const updatedState = prevState.map((ripple) => {
     if (prevState[prevState.length - 1].id === ripple.id) {
       return {
         ...ripple,
         visible: false,
       }
     }

     return ripple
   })
   return updatedState
 })
 }
```

The problem is that if I click more than `2` times really fast, it waits the `550ms` and calls the function sequentially without a delay between the calls. If I wait this 550ms myself and click over and over, it works perfectly.

I also tried with a setTimeout, but I always run into the same problem.

What I need to reach is the function to be called in `550ms`, finishes, if called again wait the 550ms, finishes, and so on for as many clicks the user did.

This is the desired result:

[image]

I got to the point where the effect works just like that, but it can't handle too many clicks in a row as the example above.

Comment: May I know where and how do you call `handleRippleRemoval`? And also a more detailed `onMouseUp` implementation would be helpful.

Comment: It's called at the onMouseUp event.

Comment: Since I don't know how the ripple is added to your `ripples` array (i.e. details in `onMouseUp`), I'm not sure if turning the 'last' ripple invisible in every `handleRippleRemoval` call is correct. I mean if you click it 3 times, the first `handleRippleRemoval` will already be cleaning up the 3rd ripple because it is the last one.

Comment: A naive and super easy try on this problem is to change your `prevState.length - 1` to `0`. Let me try to come up with a JSfiddle and explain this if you need more help.

Comment: The ripples are added through `onMouseDown`. Once the mouse is down it updates the state and adds onde more `ripple` to the beginning of the ripples array. The idea to remove the last one, is when visible changes to `visible: false` it changes the attribute `data-display` to `"none"`, which was `"visible"` this triggers a `mutation` event (each ripple has a MutationObserver). Then I can wait for the `fadeOut` animation to end and remove the ripple. That's why I need each call of `handleRippleRemoval` to wait for the other to end so I always remove the last `ripple` as soon as the mouse is up.

Comment: I also tried to change `prevState.length - 1` to `0` to remove the first element. The biggest issue is that I don't really understand why I can't make `handleRippleRemoval` to wait the `550ms` before moving on to the next `onMouseUp` call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251876/discussion-between-samchan0221-and-gabriel-ribeiro).

Comment: Sounds like you need to "Debounce"! I provided simple function to do that. Otherwise a library like `lodash` has a`debounce` method available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from a `Debounce` technique. This essentially ensures a function won't run more than once in your specified period of delay time. So 100 clicks could happen within 550ms but it would only click 1 time.

I wrote this to help me:

```
const debounce = (callback: any, wait: any) => {
  let timeoutId: any = null;
  return (...args: any) => {
    if (timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      callback.apply(null, args);
    }, wait);
  };
};

export default debounce;
```

Then import it somewhere:

`import debounce from './utils/debounce';`

Now wrap your async function with it:

```
const doFunction = debounce(async () => {
  // perform my actions but dont let
  // them happen faster than 2 seconds!
}, 2000);
```

In your case, the entire `handleRippleRemoval` function could be "debounced" (wrapped). Then whatever onClick caller you have just needs to reference the debounce-wrapped version of your function.